# Using PayPal API to facilitate user-to-user transactions

Tags: php, paypal

Will the PayPal Adaptive Payments API allow for two users connected to the application to send funds between eachother?

I'm wondering if, via the API, I can facilitate a transaction between User A and User B simply from access tokens.

Will my application be able to have User A send User B money?

Bonus Question: is it also possible to do this with Google Checkout and a Money Bookers account?

Answer (score 2):

PayPal Adaptive Payments will allow for this to happen (two users to send funds to each other). You can also send payments to up to 5 people (6 including yourself). Adaptive payments are extremely powerful for handling multiple users in a given transaction.

Additionally, PayPal must approve of any application utilizing Adaptive Payments through their review processes (which I'm sure you're aware of through reading their extensive documentation).